# ColdFusion - SOAP Service Request Error "Web service operation cannot be found."

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl

So I'm very new to SOAP and I am trying to connect to the National Weather Service's SOAP service in order to pull forecast data to display on my webpage.  Here is my short code for this process:

```
    <cfinvoke
    webservice="http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl"
    method="NDFDgen"
    returnvariable="aTemp">

        <cfinvokeargument name="latitude" value="37.94"></cfinvokeargument>
        <cfinvokeargument name="longitude" value="-75.47"></cfinvokeargument>
        <cfinvokeargument name="product" value='"glance"'></cfinvokeargument>
        <cfinvokeargument name="startTime" value="2014-05-02T12:00"></cfinvokeargument>
        <cfinvokeargument name="endTime" value="2014-05-05T12:00"></cfinvokeargument>
        <cfinvokeargument name="Unit" value='"e"'></cfinvokeargument>
        <cfinvokeargument name="weatherParameters" value="maxt = TRUE"></cfinvokeargument>
    </cfinvoke>
```

The problem is, when I try and run my webpage, I'm getting the following error:

```
Web service operation NDFDgen with parameters {Unit={"e"},startTime={2014-05-02T12:00},endTime={2014-05-05T12:00},product={"glance"},longitude={-75.47},weatherParameters={maxt = TRUE},latitude={37.94}} cannot be found.
```

I'm a bit confused since the NDFDgen operation does indeed exist in the WSDL file I am retrieving, and I have addressed all of the required parameters for the NDFDgen operation.

Link to the WSDL file I am trying to use:
http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl

Link to the functions page with required parameters:
http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/#use_it

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code? Is it perhaps something with my arguments I'm passing to SOAP? I even tried following the advice of this Stack Overflow question ([Consuming ColdFusion webservice - Web service operation with parameters {} cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362528/consuming-coldfusion-webservice-web-service-operation-with-parameters-canno)) and added the

```
refreshwsdl="yes"
```

attribute to my `<cfinvoke>`, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: This might help you: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3189949.  It basically says you have to build the SOAP message and then send it over via CFHTTP, which is what I do with SOAP webservices also. I believe that only CFC generated webservices can use CFINVOKE, but I can't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With complex web services, it is often easier to go the xml + cfhttp route, as Chester suggested. However, to answer your question, there are a few things wrong with the arguments. That is what the error message means. A method by that name may exist, but its signature does not match the values you have supplied. There is either mismatch in the *number* of arguments, or in this case, the *type* of arguments.

- According to the wsdl, the `start/endTime` values must be dates. While CF can implicitly convert a variety of U.S. date strings, it cannot parse the format you are using: `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm`. So either use [date *objects*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f7e.html), or use  "parseable", date strings such as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.
- The "weatherParameters" argument should be structure (or complex type) not a string:

  `<cfset weather = {maxt=true}>`
  `...`
  `<cfinvokeargument name="weatherParameters" value="#weather#">`
- The `Product` and `Unit` values have too many quotes. By using `value='"glance"'` you are actually including the double quotes as part of the value. That will probably cause an error because the remote web service expects to receive `glance` (no quotes).
- While it will not cause an error, you do not need to include closing tags: `</cfinvokeargument>`. If you prefer to close it, it is cleaner to use the shortcut `<cfinvokeargument ... />`

With those changes, your call should work as expected. Though you might want to consider switching to `createObject`, rather than `cfinvoke`. Then you can dump the web service object for debugging purposes. It is also less bulky IMO.

```
<cfscript>
    ws = createObject("webservice", "http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl");
    //show web service methods for debugging purposes
    writeDump(ws);

    // construct arguments
    args = {latitude="37.94"
            , longitude="-75.47"
            , product="glance"
            , startTime="2014-05-02 12:00:00"
            , endTime="2014-05-05 12:00:00"
            , Unit="e"
            , weatherParameters={maxt=true}
        };

    // call the method
    result  = ws.NDFDgen(argumentCollection=args);

    writeDump(result)
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Your `<cfscript>` worked perfectly.  Pulling 5-day forecast from NOAA as we speak.  Thanks!